# jquery mobile circular navigation back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having some problem with a jQuery mobile app back button.
The argument has been discussed a lot but I still have to find the right answer.

I have 2 html files: let's call them list.html and description.html

Each of them contains a single data-role="page".

Now, from list I' going in description using

```
$.mobile.changePage('description.html')
```

In description I have several links that I use to populate the list. So when clicking on a link I use

```
$.mobile.changePage('list.html')
```

Then from list I can go to description again and so on.

Now the problem is that if I open only 1 time list and description everything is perfect. The back button works properly.
But when I open another list it doesn't add it to the divs inside the body, but replace the old one. That way when I click back in the 1st list I see the result of the 2nd call.

I've tried with

```
window.location = 'list.html'
```

but it gives even more problems. And it's slower.

I hope I have explained my problem clearly enough. I don't know if this sound confusing.

Hope someone will be able to help.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I've tried using classes to identify the pages (with their header, content and footer) but it didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will solve your problems using something like this:

```
    <script>
        $('#pageDescription').click(function(){
            $('yourdiv').html(content);
            $.mobile.changePage('#pageList','slide');
        });
        $('#pageList').click(function(){
            $('yourdiv').html(content);
            $.mobile.changePage('#pageDescription','slide');
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageDescription">
            //Your html from description.html
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageList">
            //Your html from list.html
        </div>
    </body>
```

See more info:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Note: You will don't forget to prepare your back button!

NEW CODE:

```
<script>
    var oldHtml;
    $('div li a').click(function(){
        oldHtml = $('yourdiv').html();
        $('yourdiv').html(content);
        $.mobile.changePage('#pageDescription','slide');
    });
    $('a[data-icon=back]').click(function(){
        $('yourdiv').html(oldHtml);
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageDescription">
        //Your html from description.html
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageList">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div>
        //Your html from list.html like this
        <ul>
            <li><a>link1</a></li>
            <li><a>link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't solve the history issue: when I create a new description it will override the old one.

Comment: Where you'll create a new description? It depends of the link where you clicked?
You use $('yourdiv').append('newhtml');?

Comment: No I need to clear the previous div:
    $('#mydiv').html(content);

Comment: The problem is that when I use the back button after visiting a new description I lose the 1st.
What do you mean with prepare the back button? Sorry but I don't understand.
Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: But you want save the previous html and put new html as well? If it's true, you need use $('yourdiv').append('newhtml');, otherwise I think it isn't possible. Forget the back button.

Comment: Yes, actually I need to insert new content replacing the old one. And at the same time, when using the back button, go back to the previous content.
I tried re-creating the content passing some get parameters but android 4.0 has an issue managing get params :(
Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Alright. Now I think got it. On NEW CODE, I used a variable to save old html when you clicking on link and if you click on back button, you restart the old value.

Comment: That would take too much memory on a smartphone. Imagine having 10-20 pages saved: I think it would be too much.
The best solution was passing some parameters in the url, but for [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) android 4.0 bug I can't really use it :(

Comment: Ok. Sorry for I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help and time :)